# Get unique values in a column partitioned by a value in another column and throw it to another column that is separated by commas

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hi I have an Excel sheet that reads like this

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Eggs | Food |
| Eggs | Food |
| Eggs | Food |
| Eggs | Food |
| Bacon | Food |
| Bacon | Food |
| Bacon | Food |
| Water | Drink |
| Water | Drink |
| Coke | Drink |
| Pepsi | Drink |

is there a formula that I can add to make a Column C where the new sheet would look like this?

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Eggs | Food | Eggs, Bacon |
| Eggs | Food | Eggs, Bacon |
| Eggs | Food | Eggs, Bacon |
| Eggs | Food | Eggs, Bacon |
| Bacon | Food | Eggs, Bacon |
| Bacon | Food | Eggs, Bacon |
| Bacon | Food | Eggs, Bacon |
| Water | Drink | Water, Coke, Pepsi |
| Water | Drink | Water, Coke, Pepsi |
| Coke | Drink | Water, Coke, Pepsi |
| Pepsi | Drink | Water, Coke, Pepsi |

Comment: That depends on whether you have TEXTJOIN or not.

Comment: I have access to that formula. Still don't understand how to use it in this context.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

#Excel365 C1

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,UNIQUE(FILTER(A$1:A$99,B$1:B$99=B1)))
```

#Excel2019 C1

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,FILTERXML(CONCAT("<a>",REPT("<b>"&A$1:A$11&"</b>",B1=B$1:B$11),"</a>"),"a/b[not(preceding::*=.)]"))
```